# How do I get to the villlage without dying?

Tags: a-dark-room

Everytime I play 'a dark room' and i leave the village by clicking 'embark', everytime i try to come back I die, it says there was a beast, it does not matter where I go, when I ctry comming back I allways die, is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have a weapon with you? Do you have a combat screen before you die? Or you just killed without any other warning? If so, do you have enough curved meat to don't die from starvation? (I played the game after seeing your question, I'm near the end of the game and didn't got any problem like that)